# Unable to Create Portlet Project in Eclipse Photon for Websphere

Tags: eclipse, websphere, portlet, websphere-liberty, portal

I have installed a fresh copy of Eclipse Photon along with the Liberty server.  I followed the steps just as indicated in the IBM docs/videos.  Yet I am still not able to find anything portal or portlet related when doing File > New > Project... nor File > New > Other...

Is there a plugin that I might be missing?  Should I be looking in another area to create a portlet from scratch for IBM WebSphere?

Comment: Did the steps include installing the Liberty tools?

Comment: @nitind Yes, did that several times and it shows they are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this page [Developing portlet applications with WDT and Liberty profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-portlet-applications-wdt-liberty-profile/)?
Nor Eclipse or just WDT does provide portlet tools. You need additional plugin:

> You can simplify portlet application development by using an additional Eclipse plug-in, which is hosted at Lotus Greenhouse. Visit the [IBM Portlet Container Tools for WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=587189CF18B8BAFE85257C690038D497) site and download the required plug-in archive. To add the plug-in site archive to your list of software sources, use Help > Install New Software…. After this, you can install the new plug-in. For detailed information about this step, read the enclosed documentation of the plug-in.

You also need additional feature installed in Liberty: 
[Installing Portlet Container and Portlet Serving features on existing liberty server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_9.5.0/com.ibm.portal.doc/topics/t_install_portlet_container_serving_on_existing_server.html)

Comment: Why does this require a login to IBM?

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko If it does, it is an IBM id that you can register for free.

Comment: Those tools are not compatible with Photon.  Do I need to get an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I'm not aware of the current state of that plugin, try to contact authors of the plugin about the latest state and supported versions.